# Data access design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, php, database, data-structures, orm

I've several cases where a single entity has multiple tables in the underlying database.

When reading or writing I want to handle all of the DB queries with a single class for that object, e.g., the `SalesOrder` class has a corresponding `SalesOrderQuery` class and that class uses the underlying tables of `Sales_Order_Header` and `Sales_Line`.

Is there a design pattern name for this approach (the class doing the persistance, not the classes making of the entities being persisted)?

Comment: [Aggregate.](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe with one *single entity* and *multiple tables* is in fact an [aggregate](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/):

- The `Sales_Order_Header` table contains corresponds to the aggregate root, the order entity
- `Sales_Line` table corresponds to the line entity belonging to the  aggregate, and which is accessed through the root

The design pattern you're looking for, seems to be the [repository](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) to manage the objects in memory, which works together with [data mappers](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)

If you're looking for a reference, I'd recommend Martin Fowler's excellent book [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html), which presents all of these in full details, and some other, like [unit of work](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) for writing the related objets to the database as part of a db transaction.

Comment: Um really? `Sales_Order_Header` is the [aggregate-root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958621/whats-an-aggregate-root)? Not `SalesOrder`? I thought the idea was to abstract away the low level stuff.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I was talking about the tables that represent the entities of the aggregate in the database. I've edited to clarify

Comment: @ Christophe I just wanted to clarify my understanding of how what I have now translates to your answer.  If my SalesOrderQuery class has the SQL then my SalesOrderMapper wraps the query class and converts the SalesOrder objects to the DB array / fields needed for each SQL query, e.g., if I want to save the sales order then call `Repo->save($SalesOrder)` which calls `SalesOrderMapper->save($data)` (and converts object attributes to table columns) which calls the `SalesOrderQuery->saveHeader($data)` and `SalesOrderQuery->saveLine($data)` methods?

Comment: @PatrickSJ The mapper reads and writes specific objects to the DB without needing a query.  The repository is a "*mechanism for encapsulating storage, retrieval, and search behavior which emulates a collection of objects*" (DDD definition).  For this purpose it may use a mapper for specific objects. But it may also use queries to get a group of objects.

Comment: @Christophe I'm a bit puzzled on what you said for "it [repository] may use a mapper for specific objects".  Somehow or other the repository needs to get the data from the DB.  Why wouldn't it go through the mapper if I want a collection of SalesOrders? Or do you mean that the repo has the SQL and it somehow converts the returned array into the collection of SalesOrders (using the SalesOrderMapper?)

Comment: @PatrickSJ well, you could also use a mapper and a query for without the repository. If your domain objects are complex however, your query would have to replicate some logic that you'd have anyway in mapper.  And in addition, the mapper would always update de db directly.  What happens then if one of the transaction fails and get rollbacked ?  .  The repository gives you more flexibility by decoupling the maintenance of several objects in memory from the DB operations, as well as a better control of the aggregate and its invariants.